# Exibir o conteúdo de object NodeList

Tags: javascript

Como exibir o conteúdo recebido através de um `objectNodeList` ?

Através da seguinte função eu tento obter o conteúdo das tags pela classe.

```
function final(){
    var titulos = document.querySelectorAll(".p2.p2-resultado-busca");
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = titulos;
}
```

Entretanto ela retorna um objeto, como fazer para exibir esse conteúdo ?

Comment: isso isso isso izzas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A propriedade `innerHTML`espera uma `String`. Por isso não está funcionando.

Você pode percorrer `titulos` e usar `appendChild` para inserir cada elemento encontrado no seu elemento desejado:

```
function final(){
    var titulos = document.querySelectorAll(".p2.p2-resultado-busca");
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    //result.innerHTML = titulos;


     [].forEach.call(titulos, function(el) {
         result.appendChild(el);
     });

}
```

**Observação**: Utilizei `Array().forEach.call` nessa chamada devido ao objeto `NodeList` não possuir esse método.

Comment: show man vlw erea isso ai

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer um loop simples para obter o conteúdo:

```js
var titulos = document.querySelectorAll(".p2.p2-resultado-busca");

var content = '';
for(var i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++)
    content += titulos[i].textContent;

document.getElementById('result').textContent = content;
```

```html
<p class='p2 p2-resultado-busca'>a</p>
<p class='p2 p2-resultado-busca'>b</p>
<p class='p2 p2-resultado-busca'>c</p>

<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: mto bom man vlw