# O que é um objeto nodeList no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Sei que no JavaScript temos `array`*s* comuns, que, a maioria das linguagens possuem.

Mas as minhas dúvidas são em relação a um `nodeList` no JavaScript.

1. O que é um objeto `nodeList` no JavaScript?
2. Como posso acessar elementos de um `nodeList`?
3. Qual a diferença entre um `array` convencional e um `nodeList`?
4. Qual a sua utilidade?

Comment: Não entendi o porque do downvote. Poderia colocar nos comentários por favor? Para que eu possa melhorar a pergunta, se esse é o caso, ou, se for uma duplicata.

Comment: Resumindo, é uma lista de nós (sejam eles elementos, textos ou até comentários), da mesma for que uma array comum, a diferença está em `NodeList.prototype` e `Array.prototype`, a utilidade é que é uma array especial para uma função específica, mas dificilmente você irá criar um deles diretamente

Comment: Dando um exemplo comum do ponto 3 não consegue utlizar `map` num `NodeList` ao passo que num array consegue. Algo como `document.querySelectorAll("li").map(x => x.textContent)` para obter um array de textos dos vários `<li>` não funciona porque não é um array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NodeList` é uma classe interna do JavaScript que possui a seguinte interface:

```
[Exposed=Window]
interface NodeList {
  getter Node? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  iterable<Node>;
};
```

Isto é, um objeto de `NodeList` possuirá:

- Um método `item` que recebe um argumento `index` numérico e retorna um elemento `Node`;
- Um atributo `length` numérico;
- Um iterável de elementos `Node`;

Quando se tem uma estrutura baseada em árvore, o nó `Node` é o elemento básico da estrutura. No caso do JavaScript, o DOM é uma árvore de nós. A classe `NodeList` representa um conjunto desses nós, sendo retornado, por exemplo, pelas funções `document.querySelectorAll` ou o atributo `element.childNodes`.

Você pode acessar um dos elementos da lista através do método `item` identificando o índice que deseja acessar ou iterar sobre o objeto.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// Acessando via método item:
console.log( lis.item(0) );

// Iterando sobre o objeto:
for (let li of lis) {
  console.log(li);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

O `NodeList`, embora se assemelhe a um *array*, não possui equivalências. Um é uma coleção de nós, outro é um... *array*. O `NodeList`, por exemplo, sempre representará uma coleção de elementos do tipo `Node`, ordenados conforme suas respectivas posições dentro da árvore e é imutável, você não é capaz de adicionar um novo elemento a um `NodeList` - precisa alterar a árvore diretamente. Já um *array* é um conjunto de valores sem relação direta entre si.

A utilidade dele é intrínseca em sua definição: representar, como objeto, uma coleção de nós na forma de lista.

Outras leituras relacionadas:

- [Qual a diferença de NodeList para HTMLCollection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17237/5878)
- [Qual a diferença entre HTMLCollection, NodeList e Object?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304324/5878)
- [Exibir o conteúdo de object NodeList](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168270/5878)

Answer (score 8):

O que é um objeto nodeList no JavaScript?

Como o próprio nome diz é uma lista nós do DOM. [Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Isto inclui os atributos e os textos do nós.

> Como posso acessar elementos de um nodeList?

Como qualquer coleção de dados, acessa cada nó através de um índice para o elemento que deseja. Uma das formas mais comuns de realizar isto é com um `for`.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var checkbox of list) {
    checkbox.checked = true;
}
```

Quase tudo de um *array* funciona nele, mas é uma coleção com outra estrutura. E ele não provê acesso em forma de dicionário, portanto não pode acessar pelos nomes dos elementos encontrados no elemento selecionado.

```
document.querySelectorAll("p")[1] //pega o segundo elemento da lista de nós de p
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/NodeList.js).

É possível convertê-lo para um `Array` e acessá-lo desta forma. O *array* será estático, ou sejam os dados não alteram. O `nodeLIst` é vivo, então por ser uma referência direta para o DOM, conforme o DOM vaio sendo modificado pela página o conteúdo encontrado ali sofre reflexo dessas alterações do DOM. Nem todas iterações com uma variável que tenha um `nodeList` serão iguais.

> Qual a diferença entre um array convencional e um nodeList?

Um *array* tem todas posições em sequência

> Qual a sua utilidade?

Ele armazena uma coleção de elementos do DOM selecionados por uma das funções da API do *browser* selecionando o que deseja. Aí você pode fazer várias manipulações em cada um desses elementos. Geralmente ele é útil quando precisa fazer operações em todos os elementos ou pelo menos uma parcela deles. Entenda que manipular não precisa ser mexer, pode ser ser só verificar. O que pode fazer individualmente com um elemento neste caso pode fazer de forma geral.

A função mais comum que retorna esta coleção é a [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). A propriedade [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) também tem uma referência para isto.